# Disable form submitting by clicking enter key on input type - file

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, enter

I want to prevent form submitting by hittiing enter key on **input type = file**. I searched the jquery script to do it. It is ok for input type = text but, if hit on input type file, the login page is displayed after log out. I'm using jsp and jquery. And also **my brower is IE9**. Is there something wrong in my code?

jquery :

```
$(function(){
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //$('#fil_CsvImp_refer').click();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("input[type=text]").keypress(function(ev) {
        if ((ev.which && ev.which === 13) ||
            (ev.keyCode && ev.keyCode === 13)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    $("input[type=file]").keypress(function(ev) {
        if ((ev.which && ev.which === 13) ||
            (ev.keyCode && ev.keyCode === 13)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

jsp :

```
<s:form action="" method="POST" name="frm_CsvImp_import" id="frm_CsvImp_import"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:file key="fil_CsvImp_refer" name="fil_CsvImp_refer" cssClass="mediuminput" accept=".csv" />
<input type="button" class="" value="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Does the js console show something  ?
whad does it mean this: " it goes log out and displays log in page" (give some context) ?

Comment: I means that I hit entery key on input type - file, login JSP page is displayed after log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me (in a file input, plain html on firefox, chrome (both upToDAte) and jquery 1.11):

```
     $("input[type=file]").keypress(function(ev) {
               return false;
               //ev.preventDefault(); //works as well

     });
```

Also notice that, not just "enter" key trigger the browser dialog (barspace does it as well).

Comment: After restarted the eclipse and cleared the cache on IE9, my jquery works correctly. btw, waht is barspace? pls explain me if possible. thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry was a typo wanted to write "spacebar" (key in the keyboard). If you check only by the enter keyCode will work, but also the spacebar key will trigger the browse for file dialog just like the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

*I think i didn't understood your question clearly*

```
$(document).ready() {
$('input:file').keypress(function() {
  //your operations
});
}
```

*(OR)*
once try this,hope it helps you

```
$(function(){

$("#frm_CsvImp_import").on("change", "#INPUTTYPEID( or.CLASSNAME)", function(){

//do your operations
});

});
```